# RemoveClass of other childeren in same parent div

Tags: html, jquery, css, radio-button

I am trying to replace my radio circles by div's.

The selecting by clicking on the divs works.
The highlighting of the selected div works.

But how can i remove the "selected" class of the other childeren in the same parent when i select one of the other options?

My JS is now:

```
$('.option').click(function() {
    $('input', this).prop("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass('optionSelected');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S7Js8/

Comment: What version of CSS are you using? This is done much simpler in CSS3 but if you need backwards compatibility before IE9 it won't work. Either way I can give you direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `siblings()` to target the sibling div's,

```
$('.option').click(function() {
    $('input', this).prop("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass('optionSelected')
           .siblings()
           .removeClass('optionSelected');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/S7Js8/1/)

Comment: Thanks! Works for me :) i was almost sure there was something like "siblings" but didn't know what to google for! haha!

Comment: @PowerGuitarist - jQuery has a way with names! Remember to accept the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('.option').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.option').removeClass('optionSelected');
    $('input', this).prop("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass('optionSelected');
});
```

If all the options are siblings, then you can do this,

```
$('.option').click(function() {
    $(this).siblings('.option').removeClass('optionSelected');
    $('input', this).prop("checked", true);
    $(this).addClass('optionSelected');
});
```